# .htaccess rewrite from index.cgi?action= to / or index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

We moved from a forum provider, to our own forum and hosting.
The old forum used index.cgi?action=
Some times it is index.cgi?action=viewprofile&user=USERNAME
etc....

I would like to redirect any index.cgi?action= request to http://www.example.com/ or index.php

Also I would like to redirect: speller/spellchecker.html to http://www.example.com/ or index.php

All redirect, I would like to be 301.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to redirect `index.cgi?action=viewprofile` to `index.php?action=viewprofile` or just to `index.php`?

Comment: just index.php or redirect to http://www.example.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this will work for you:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} action
RewriteRule index\.cgi http://www.example.com [L,R=301]

RewriteRule speller/spellchecker.html http://www.example.com [L,R=301]
```

Every request to index.cgi containing `action` will be redirected, every request to speller/spellchecker.html, too.

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try in the morning.